# Does jQuery have, or is there a jQuery plugin, with a built-in function for listening to CSS3 animation events (e.g. animationEnd)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

I looked around and couldn't find any. In my app in order to trigger an animation on an element, I add a class with that desired animation to the element. Then I want to listen to the animation end event and run some code when it is fired.

As far as I can tell jQuery does not have this feature implemented already in a *cross-browser* way already (e.g. `$(document).on('animationEnd', 'selector', callback)`).

While it is easy to implement this manually, I was wondering if there's a third-party library available that does this already?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
transitionend
webkitTransitionEnd
oTransitionEnd
MSTransitionEnd
```

You can use something like:

```
$('#yourelement').addClass('animatedClass').on('transitionend', function(e) {
 // ... do stuff.
);
```

There is also

```
 :animated
```

which you can test against,

```
 if ( $('#yourelement:not(:animated)') ) { ...
 if ( $('#yourelement').is(':animated') ) { ...
```

Hope that sets you on the right path =)

Comment: Thanks, but the event I am interested in is actually `animationEnd`. And what I was looking for, was a library that allows me to write `$(foo).on('animationEnd', ...)`, rather than `$(foo).on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationEnd', ...)`.

Answer (score -1):

Listen to all of the prefixed events also.